# Web-based code editor plugin (for Css & Less) with syntax highlight 

Tags: jquery, css, less

Is there a proved/simple way to create code editor foe CSS/LESS files inside my web application? (like on github or any web based IDE). Maybe there some good plugin to achieve that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Github uses [Ace editor](http://ace.ajax.org/) I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 7):

Just give http://codemirror.net/ a try...